# Implementing async/task/await in a multi-tier windows form application

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, task

I would appreciate some help with async/Task implementation in my Windows Form application.

In this app, I retrieve data from the datacenter SQl server database using WCF services, so part of this code runs on the client and some on the datacenter server where it retrieves the data and returns it.  I’d like to optimize the code using async/Task on the clien or server or preferably both. The example code starts with a Windows Form with a button, when the button is clicked it gets a value from the database, displays it and updates a local variable.

I’m not clear if I can simply implement async/Task and Task.Run in the first button click event or whether the code should be cascaded through all methods, or something in between. I'm also not clear on how to handle the wcf service.

I’ve created a simplified example of the code, pretty close to sequentially.
In this code, the return value updates the windows form.  I’d like to see how this code is optimized using async/Task await for this purpose and what would be different if the code did not return a value.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int returnvalue = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowcount = ChangeProductPrice(.05m);
        txtResult.Text = rowcount.ToString();
    }

    private int ChangeProductPrice(decimal priceincrease)
    {
        int rv = MyData.WebServiceObject.ChangePrice(priceincrease);
        UpdateLocalVariables(rv);
        return rv;
    }
    private void UpdateLocalVariables(int rv)
    {
        returnvalue = rv;
    }

}
public static class MyData
{
    private static IMyDataWCFService _webserviceobject = null;

    public static IMyDataWCFService WebServiceObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (_webserviceobject is null)
            {
                //...code to initialize it
            }
            return _webserviceobject;
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyDataWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int ChangePrice(decimal priceincrease);
}
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

public class MyDataWCFService : IMyDataWCFService
{
    private MyDataService _serviceObject = null;
    private MyDataService ServiceObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (_serviceObject == null)
            {
                _serviceObject = new MyDataService();
            }
            return _serviceObject;
        }
    }
    public int ChangePrice(decimal priceincrease)
    {
        return ServiceObject.ChangePrice(priceincrease);
    }
}
public class MyDataService  //running on server
{
    public int ChangePrice(decimal priceincrease)
    {
        int rows = 0;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = this.GetSqlConnection();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "mysp_UpdatePrice";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rate", priceincrease));
                conn.Open();
                rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProcessError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                ReturnSqlConnection(conn);
        }
        return rows;
    }
    private SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        //dostuff;
        return new SqlConnection();
    }
    private void ProcessError(Exception ex)
    {
        //dostuff;
    }
    private void ReturnSqlConnection(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        //dostuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, did you use Visual Studio to generate the client proxy or are you creating the proxy manually?

Comment: async/wait is TAP. For the generated service proxies there is also APM (now considered old). Ref doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/

Comment: The server side implementation of the service is irrelevant for the client. The important is the implmentation of the service client. Can you post the method signatures of the client, instead?